# "probe of spi0.0 failed with error -16" error when interfacing SPI LCD

Tags: linux, connection, arm, error-logging

I have a arm-based computer with armbian OS, and a LCD that I want to connect it with SPI protocol. When I use this command:

```
sudo modprobe fbtft_device custom name=fb_ili9341 gpios=reset:198,dc:201,led:6 speed=16000000 rotate=90 bgr=1
```

I get this error in `dmesg`:

```
[   68.421997] fbtft_device:  SPI devices registered:
[   68.422019] fbtft_device:      spidev spi0.0 33000kHz 8 bits mode=0x00
[   68.422029] fbtft_device:  'fb' Platform devices registered:
[   68.422115] fbtft_device: Deleting spi0.0
[   68.422631] fbtft_device:  GPIOS used by 'fb_ili9341':
[   68.422648] fbtft_device:    'reset' = GPIO198
[   68.422656] fbtft_device:    'dc' = GPIO201
[   68.422662] fbtft_device:    'led' = GPIO6
[   68.422669] fbtft_device:  SPI devices registered:
[   68.422679] fbtft_device:      fb_ili9341 spi0.0 16000kHz 8 bits mode=0x00
[   68.433490] fb_ili9341 spi0.0: fbtft_request_gpios: gpio_request_one('reset'=198) failed with -16
[   68.433657] fb_ili9341: probe of spi0.0 failed with error -16
```

I checked the error number here http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/uapi/asm-generic/errno-base.h#L15 and it says : `Device or resource busy` 
But pins are free and changing the pin didn't solve the problem!

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did comment this line `#gpio_sunxi` in the `/etc/modules` file and the problem solved!

Comment: Hi! What did #gpio_sunxi do?